# Plugin.InAppBilling.PurchaseAsync never returns

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am attempting to use the InAppBilling plugin to make purchases on Android and I am using the code described here: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/PurchaseNonConsumable.html

Everything seems to work correctly and I am able to complete the purchase. However the await PurchaseAsync call never returns after the purchase is complete. The purchase does go through, however, and if I later call the GetPurchasesAsync function, it shows that I do own the item.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I apparently did not read the documentation properly and was missing the OnActivityResult override in the MainActivity.